# AChartEngine max zoom in and zoom out

Tags: android, graph, charts, zooming, achartengine

I have a problem with setting limits on zoom in and zoom out.
I tried to set limits using this code

```
mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double [] {0.8, 1.2, 0, 0});
```

but it doesn't works correctly. (i cant zoom out and zooming in is working like previously) I also tried to use **ZoomListener** like this, but i dont know how to lock zooming while **isMin(zoomRate)** is called

```
 mChart.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {

            private float zoomRate = 0;

            @Override
            public void zoomReset() {
            }

            @Override
            public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG + " zoom", arg0.getZoomRate() +"");
                zoomRate += -1 + arg0.getZoomRate() ;
                isMin(zoomRate);
            }

            private void isMin(float zoomRate) {
                if(zoomRate > 0.5) 
                {
                    Log.i(TAG + " zoom", "MIN!");   
                    //??
                }
            }
        }, true, true);
```

thanks for your help and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, based on the zoom limits you have set, it works correctly. If you are trying to disable zooming, you need:

```
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false)
```